# Getting both max and min sum values on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the tables:

```
TABLE A
Debtornum,debtor_name,debtor_svc_type,Has_Myaccount,debtor_class,debtor_email,debtor_svs_state,Do_Not_contact,account_status,payment_code
12345,John smith,B,Y,R,12345@gmail.com,CO,0,A,CSH
12346,John smith,B,Y,R,12346@yahoo.com,CO,1,F,autop*y
12347,Jane Smith,E,N,R,,MN,1,A,CSH
12348,Jane Smith,E,N,R,,MN,1,F,_recurpay

TABLE B
Debtornum,Premnum,invoice_nr,usage_mnthly_kwh,usage_rate
12345,3000001,100001,2.3,T19
12346,3000002,100002,2.2,T19
12347,3000003,100003,5.7,T33
12348,3000004,100004,34.7,T19
```

I want to get the min, max of the total debtor usage grouped by class and account status.

I've tried:

```
select t.debtor_class, t.account_status, min(t.sum1), max(t.sum1) MaxUsage
FROM
(SELECT a.debtor_class, a.account_status, sum(b.usage_mnthly_kwh) sum1
FROM  debtor_table_a a
INNER JOIN usage_table_b b
ON a."Debtornum" = b."Debtornum"
GROUP BY a.debtor_class, a.account_status) t
group by t.debtor_class, t.account_status;
```

but the min and max values are somehow identical - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the exact output you expect here.

Comment: `sum(b.usage_mnthly_kwh) sum1` is a single value, so `min(t.sum1), max(t.sum1)` will the same thing. I believe you are looking for `min(usage_mnthly_kwh)` and `max(usage_mnthly_kwh)`, but you will  need to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, what you really want is

1. first get total debtor  usage  in each (debtor, debtor_class, account_status)
2. then get min and max of total debtor usage in each (debtor_class, account_status)

With that in mind, the provide query is missing "Debtornum" in the inner group by condition.

Here is the new [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51f4fd/2) to get the result you want:

```
select t.debtor_class, t.account_status, min(t.sum1), max(t.sum1) MaxUsage
FROM
(SELECT a.debtor_class, a.account_status, sum(b.usage_mnthly_kwh) sum1
FROM  debtor_table_a a
INNER JOIN usage_table_b b
ON a."Debtornum" = b."Debtornum"
GROUP BY a."Debtornum", a.debtor_class, a.account_status) t
group by t.debtor_class, t.account_status;
```

| debtor_class | account_status | min | maxusage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R | A | 2.3 | 5.7 |
| R | F | 2.2 | 34.7 |